# Hello, I want to ensure that my div is always larger than my content with nowrap text, may I know how is this possible?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

this is how my window looks like currently
[image]

I hope to keep the sizing properly, however, as I reduce the size of the screen, the text
(with white-space set to nowrap) becomes like this.

[image]

May I know if it is possible to make sure that the div will always be larger than the text (however each of the div element is still of diff size as I want them to fit the word itself, like BnS should have a smaller div than University Visit.

Here is my code CSS for the element

```
.event-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.event-nav-item {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 50px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.event-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.event-nav-item {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 50px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

try this... this will work as you need. If possible let it be wrap as every overflowed text will collapse at some point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).